# NuGet on Linux: Error getting response stream

Tags: linux, mono, nuget

I'm trying to run NuGet on Linux (Ubuntu 12). I have Mono 3.0.6 (compiled from source).

```
$ mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 .nuget/NuGet.exe update -self
Checking for updates from https://nuget.org/api/v2/.
Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure
```

The error is due to some certificate (the nuget.org one most likely) not being trusted, I gather. This [blog post has more details](http://monomvc.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/nuget-on-mono/).

So I've run:

```
$ mozroots --import --sync
$ certmgr -ssl https://go.microsoft.com
$ certmgr -ssl https://nugetgallery.blob.core.windows.net
$ certmgr -ssl https://nuget.org
```

... to no avail.

NuGet Version is 2.3.0.0 (although I started out with some older version that also did not work either).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you getting the exact same error after importing the SSL certificates ?

Comment: I honestly don't remember if it was different before importing the certificates.

Comment: I just want to link this related, very helpful article http://dlafferty.blogspot.no/2013/08/building-your-microsoft-solution-with.html

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I was able to get this working by importing the certificates into the machine store and not the user store, which is the default:

```
$ sudo mozroots --import --machine --sync
$ sudo certmgr -ssl -m https://go.microsoft.com
$ sudo certmgr -ssl -m https://nugetgallery.blob.core.windows.net
$ sudo certmgr -ssl -m https://nuget.org
```

I verified that before I did this — even after having done the original user store-based commands — [the tlstest.exe tool](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security) failed, and after importing into the machine store it succeeded.

And, most important to me of course, nuget started working then too. :)

Comment: If you get an error on the first command - please see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/331519/mozroots-command-fails-with-unsupported-hash-error

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get nuget working on cloud9. :-)

Comment: This helped me to install OmniSharp (for Mono) on Ubuntu 14.04/Trusty, which otherwise fails with an obtuse error....

Comment: @EdwardGarson glad to hear it! if appropriate, you could post the error message here to give this answer some more google-fu

Comment: @AaronLerch you are right:      [...].nuget/NuGet.targets: error : Command 'mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 [...]/NuGet.exe install "packages.config" -source ""   -o "/opt/OmniSharpServer/packages"' exited with code: 1.

Comment: First command fails with: Downloading from 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1'...
Couldn't retrieve the file using the supplied information.

Comment: When running the last command, the output ends with: "*** WARNING: Certificate signature is INVALID *** Import this certificate into the CA store ?". Is this normal? This is a bit scary.

Comment: First command failed for me too, but I did a `nuget restore` afterwards and it worked like a charm.

Comment: mozroots is deprecated now - can we get an updated fix?

Comment: I don't use mono or .NET anymore, so I'm not equipped to update it. Hopefully someone else solves any current problems and can either update my answer or add a new one.