# Unable to install any NuGet package in Monodevelop

Tags: mono, nuget, monodevelop, ubuntu-14.04

I compiled and installed Monodevelop as detailed [here](http://www.davidloo.com/?p=479):

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
cd monodevelop
./configure --profile=stable
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then I created a new MVC3 project and tried to add a package with NuGet. However, any package I try to add, I get an error similar with this one in the Package Console:

```
Adding Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure... Installing
'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'. Could not find a part of the path
"/tmp/nuget/bf2agvz5.hwr/lib/net40/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll".
```

Example:

> Adding Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers... Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (≥ 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)'. Attempting to
>   resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (≥ 3.2.3 && <
>   3.3.0)'. Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData (≥ 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)'. Attempting
>   to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data'. The
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Razor package has a license agreement which is
>   available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm
>   Please review this license agreement and remove the package if you do
>   not accept the agreement. Check the package for additional
>   dependencies which may also have license agreements. Using this
>   package and any dependencies constitutes your acceptance of these
>   license agreements. The Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages package has a
>   license agreement which is available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm
>   Please review this license agreement and remove the package if you do
>   not accept the agreement. Check the package for additional
>   dependencies which may also have license agreements. Using this
>   package and any dependencies constitutes your acceptance of these
>   license agreements. The Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data package has a
>   license agreement which is available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm
>   Please review this license agreement and remove the package if you do
>   not accept the agreement. Check the package for additional
>   dependencies which may also have license agreements. Using this
>   package and any dependencies constitutes your acceptance of these
>   license agreements. The Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData package has
>   a license agreement which is available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm
>   Please review this license agreement and remove the package if you do
>   not accept the agreement. Check the package for additional
>   dependencies which may also have license agreements. Using this
>   package and any dependencies constitutes your acceptance of these
>   license agreements. The Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers package has a
>   license agreement which is available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm
>   Please review this license agreement and remove the package if you do
>   not accept the agreement. Check the package for additional
>   dependencies which may also have license agreements. Using this
>   package and any dependencies constitutes your acceptance of these
>   license agreements. Installing 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'.
>   Could not find a part of the path
>   "/tmp/nuget/bf2agvz5.hwr/lib/net40/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll".

Or:

> Adding Newtonsoft.Json... Newtonsoft.Json Package contains PowerShell
>   scripts which will not be run. Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8'.
>   Could not find a part of the path
>   "/tmp/nuget/3e1zcrod.0p6/lib/net20/Newtonsoft.Json.dll".

Do you have any ideas?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and MonoDevelop 6.0.

Thanks

Comment: Do the files that NuGet is failing to find exist? NuGet will unzip the packages to the temp directory.

Comment: Nope, they don't exist.

Comment: What version of Mono do you have installed? I am using MonoDevelop 6.0 built from source on Ubuntu 14.04 and cannot reproduce this problem with NuGet.

Comment: I installed mono-complete 3.2.8 from the store. 

Another thing, when I compiled monodevelop, I had to run "sudo make", because otherwise I got a similar error as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793207/error-when-compiling-monodevelop-5-3-on-linux and despite running "mozroots --import --sync" I still couldn't get make to complete successfully, unless sudo-ed.

Comment: I have Mono 3.12 installed not built from source though - http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: @MattWard Thanks for the help, Matt. I found a solution and posted an aanswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem appeared due to the previous installation of monodevelop. I had monodevelop 4.0.12 installed from Ubuntu packages and when I decided to compile monodevelop from the source code, I uninstalled this version. However, running *sudo apt-get remove monodevelop* was not enough.

I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove monodevelop
```

to remove the configuration files as well and then I compiled again monodevelop 6 and the NuGet module works fine now.

One more hint for those in need, you can get some more information when running monodevelop compiled from the source code, if you run:

```
make run
```

This will show a lot of messages in the console, while monodevelop is running.

Comment: yeah, and by using `make run` you don't need to install monodevelop in your system, so you don't need the last step `sudo make install` which would conflict with the currently-installed-version of monodevelop