# nuget command line utility package restore with mono on ubuntu

Tags: mono, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to restore packages with the `nuget restore` command using the `nuget.exe` command line utility.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and have just performed `apt-get update`.

Calling `mono --version` returns:
`Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)`

Here is my exact call and response:

```
$ mono nuget.exe restore
WARNING: The initialization function tries to access Value on this instance
WARNING: The initialization function tries to access Value on this instance
WARNING: The initialization function tries to access Value on this instance
WARNING: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure
Unable to find version '2.0.14' of package 'FSharp.Data'.
Unable to find version '1.3.0.1' of package 'FsUnit'.
Unable to find version '1.3.0.1' of package 'FsUnit.Sample'.
Unable to find version '2.6.3' of package 'NUnit'.
```

I have tried with and without a `nuget.config` file in the same folder.

What's going wrong and what can I do to solve?

Comment: found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181888/nuget-on-linux-error-getting-response-stream

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe has to do with root security certificates.

Enter the following command in your terminal:

```
mozroots --import --sync
```

As per @ahri below, here is a more up-to-date answer:

```
mozroots --import --sync --url https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/tip/security‌​/nss/lib/ckfw/builti‌​ns/certdata.txt
```

[Source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mozroots)

Comment: A more recent update, as this didn't work for me: `mozroots --import --sync --url https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/tip/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt`

Comment: @ScottWeldon It appears to have moved to https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/tip/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt now. Perhaps the easiest thing is to simply search google for "mozilla certdata.txt" as that's how I'm hunting it down.