# NuGet with Mono on Linux: Error getting response stream

Tags: c#, ubuntu, docker, mono, nuget

This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181888/nuget-on-linux-error-getting-response-stream) but an update because the fix mentioned in that question is now deprecated, and does not work.

I'm running Ubuntu in a Docker container, and nuget is unable to restore on a C# solution, giving the error `Error: SecureChannelFailure` repeatedly when running `nuget restore mySolution.sln`.

From the old StackOverflow question, I tried the `mozroots` command, but get `WARNING: mozroots is deprecated, please move to cert-sync instead.`

I then ran my `cert-sync` manually, although it is noted that it is automatically run on mono's install anyway. No help.

Running the other suggested commands to add certs yielded no results either:

```
$ certmgr -ssl https://go.microsoft.com
$ certmgr -ssl https://nugetgallery.blob.core.windows.net
$ certmgr -ssl https://nuget.org
```

Although they seem to have added the certs, I am still unable to run `nuget restore`.

Other maybe-helpful info:

```
Ubuntu version 16.04 in docker container
Mono JIT compiler version 5.0.1.1
NuGet Version: 2.12.0.0
```

What is the post-mozroots-deprecation accepted method to fix this issue?

Comment: `mozroots` can still be used. You can use it till it is removed. Typical usage of `cert-sync` can be found at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.12.0/ or http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/. The NuGet version you use is too old. Can you upgrade it and try again?

Comment: `mozroots` results in the error `Couldn't retrieve the file using the supplied information.`

Comment: `nuget is already the newest version (2.12+mono-0xamarin5+debian7b1).`

Comment: @Dagrooms Nuget later version is `4.1.0`,  Use `nuget update -self` to update it (depending upon permissions, you make have to use `sudo`....)

Comment: It stays at 2.12 after running that command.